# Cómo incluir una constante en la URL de una API en .NET 5?

Tags: c#, api, .net, mvc

Necesito poder incluir en la url de mi API una constante que tengo definida en otra clase.

Ahora mismo, mi controlador tendría el siguiente encabezado:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action])]
public class TestController: Controller
{
}
```

Por lo que el endpoint final quedaría como **api/Test/[action]**.
Lo que necesito es que mi api tenga los endpoints en el siguiente formato: **api/Test/v1/[action]**, siendo v1 la variable que yo tengo definida en mi otra clase...

Alguien sabe cómo podría conseguirse esto?

Gracias!

Comment: Esta otra clase que seria? otro controlador?

Comment: creo que sería `[Route("api/[controller]/{v1}/[action])]`

Answer (score 0):

tiene que hacer los siguiente

```
[Route("api/[controller]/" + Clase.Constante + "/[action])]
```

Donde clase es tu clase y constante es tu constante definida en la clase